# aggregate different rows by different functions in R

Tags: r, function, aggregate, summary

I have the following data frame:
[image]

(dput() for testing bellow)

> ```
>     structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
> 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "797 Fleet", class = "factor"), 
>     V2 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
>     5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Available Hours", "Cycle Time", 
>     "Performance", "Production time", "Units"), class = "factor"), 
>     V3 = c(51, 2989.601111, 2498.85, 540.8754973, 39.93337086, 
>     52, 30010.73389, 24946.62833, 529.4659407, 40.81742793, 36, 
>     20778.5525, 17174.18722, 535.7960907, 40.36234152, 19)), .Names = c("V1", 
> "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
> ```

i need to aggregate the data but with different functions for different features;
for the 797 fleet, the units and production time should be added, but the performance an cycle time should be averaged.

I have just tried aggregate with two functions, but i get two columns one with all added and other with all averaged and i need only one column.

How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
fun_list <- list("Units" = sum, "Production time" = sum, "Performance" = mean, "Cycle Time" = mean)
setDT(df)[V2 %in% names(fun_list), .(res = fun_list[[as.character(.BY[[2]])]](V3)),by = .(V1, V2)]

#          V1              V2         res
#1: 797 Fleet           Units   158.00000
#2: 797 Fleet Production time 44619.66555
#3: 797 Fleet     Performance   535.37918
#4: 797 Fleet      Cycle Time    40.37105
```

Let's unpack this solution a little. First, we store a map of the functions we want to apply to each of the values in `V2`. This list is simply a list of functions. E.g. `"Units" = sum` means we want to apply `sum` to the `"Units"` group. To see how this works try: `fun_list[["Units"]](c(1,2,3))`.

We then use this in our group by operation in `data.table`. We use the `V2` value stored in `.BY` to index our function list. That is for each `V2` value we choose a function from our list to apply. This is accomplished by `fun_list[[as.character(.BY[[2]])]]` (Note we need to `as.character` since `.BY` is a factor). Lastly we apply that function to `V3` which is what `(V3)` does in the last part of the code `fun_list[[as.character(.BY[[2]])]](V3))`!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct way to do that with aggregate...
You would need first to create separate datasets with you features of interest and then aggregate using the desired function:

```
t1<-rbind(subset(test, test$V2=="Units"), subset(test, test$V2=="Production time"))
aggregate(.~V2, data=t1, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using split() to split the dataframe ito a list of dataframes , one list item (a dataframe) per level of V2, then separate lapply functions to create the summaries with the desired aggregate function.  Finally combine all back together using Reduce and rbind

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "797 Fleet", class = "factor"), 
               V2 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
                                5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Available Hours", "Cycle Time", 
                                                                    "Performance", "Production time", "Units"), class = "factor"), 
               V3 = c(51, 2989.601111, 2498.85, 540.8754973, 39.93337086, 
                      52, 30010.73389, 24946.62833, 529.4659407, 40.81742793, 36, 
                      20778.5525, 17174.18722, 535.7960907, 40.36234152, 19)),  .Names = c("V1", 
                                                                                           "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))


df_list <- split(df, df$V2)


summary <- c(

  lapply(df_list[c("Units", "Production time")], 
       function(df) {aggregate(V3 ~ V1 + V2, data = df, sum)})
 ,
  lapply(df_list[c("Performance", "Cycle Time")], 
       function(df) {aggregate(V3 ~ V1 + V2, data = df, mean)})

   )

Reduce(rbind, summary)
#>          V1              V2          V3
#> 1 797 Fleet           Units   158.00000
#> 2 797 Fleet Production time 44619.66555
#> 3 797 Fleet     Performance   535.37918
#> 4 797 Fleet      Cycle Time    40.37105
```